# Plot Y-Range on Mathematica

Tags: mathematica, graphing-functions, computational-mathematics, computer-algebra-systems

I have a plot that I would like to slightly manipulate in Mathematica. Here is the code I am entering:

> Plot[{x, 2^x, log_2(x)}, {x, -1, 3}]

As you can see $x$, $2^x$, and $log_2(x)$ are all plotted on a basic plot between $x = -1$ and $x = 3$. The x-range was easy to restrict, but how can I also restrict the y-range?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ahh... got it. Use PlotRange -> {lowerY, upperY}

> Plot[{x, 2^x, Log2[x]}, {x, -1, 3}, PlotRange -> {-2, 4}]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, but actually you have to also include the x domain in the PlotRange function...so:

```
Plot[{x, 2^x, Log2[x]}, {x, -1, 3}, PlotRange -> {{-1,3},{-2, 4}}]
```